# Clarification on a theorem of E. Michael

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

In Lemma 7.3.1 in [Topologies on spaces of subsets](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1951-071-01/S0002-9947-1951-0042109-4/) Michael states that if $X$ is a connected Hausdorff space and $f : \mathcal{F}_n(X) \to X$ is a selection, then $f(E)$ is the first (<) element of $E$ for every $E \in \mathcal{F}_n(X)$, where $x<y$ if and only if $f(\{x,y\})=x$. His proof goes as follows: [image]

My problem is in part (b). I think that if $y\in E$, then it is not true that $E\in \mathfrak{M}'$ (since $y\not\in V$) and, therefore, $\mathfrak{M}'$ is not useful for verifying that $\mathfrak{E}$ is open as he says. If my reasoning is correct, I would please like to know if it is possible to fix Michael's proof, or if there is some other way to prove his original statement.